# デスクトップにあるcsvファイル名「fm_data20??_??_??」を検索してリネームさせたい

Tags: python, python3, selenium

#### 前提・実現したいこと

デスクトップにあるcsvファイル名「fm_data20??*??*??」を検索して「アップロード.csv」に変更したいです。

「fm_data20??*??*??」は日々変わるため、任意の一文字「?」を入れています。
import osとimport globをインポートするのだと思うのですが、
コードの書き方がイマイチよくわかりません。

よろしくお願いします。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-1abdd7eb4bb9> in <module>
      9 
     10 # ファイル名の変更
---> 11 os.rename(path1, path2)
     12 
     13 # ファイルの存在確認

TypeError: rename: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```py
import os
import glob

# 変更前ファイル
path1 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\tani\Desktop/fm_data20??_??_??.csv')

# 変更後ファイル
path2= r'C:\Users\tani\Desktop\アップロード.csv'

# ファイル名の変更 
os.rename(path1, path2) 

# ファイルの存在確認 
print(os.path.exists(path2))
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python 3.7.3
Windows7
jupyter notebook
chromedriver

Answer (score 3):

`glob.glob`はマッチするパスのリストを返します。

[glob --- Unix 形式のパス名のパターン展開 — Python 3.7.6 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

> pathname (パスの指定を含んだ文字列でなければいけません) にマッチする、空の可能性のあるパス名のリストを返します。pathnameは (/usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefileのように) 絶対パスでも、(../../Tools/*/*.gifのように) 相対パスでもよく、シェル形式のワイルドカードを含んでいてもかまいません。結果には (シェルと同じく)
>   壊れたシンボリックリンクも含まれます。

そのため返されたリストの要素を`for`文などを使って`rename`に渡してやる必要があります。
(`/`になっている部分を`\`に変えてあります)

```
path_list = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\tani\Desktop\fm_data20??_??_??.csv')

path2= r'C:\Users\tani\Desktop\アップロード.csv'

for path1 in path_list:
    os.rename(path1, path2)
```

とはいえ、複数のファイルを`アップロード.csv`にリネームしたいということはないと思うので、質問者さんの目的に適うのであれば、空のリストではないことをチェックして、第１要素を渡してしまってもよいでしょう。

```
if path_list:
    os.rename(path_list[0], path2)
```

Comment: 解決しました！助かりました

Comment: @Tanichan 過去の質問も含め、もし回答によって解決した場合には(回答を)承認してあげてください。 参考ヘルプ: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)